# aws-sam local tmp directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I'm working on some functions to generate documents and email them off, that all works but it's hard to debug waiting for the email.

I write the file to the lambda tmp folder, and I can see it there by listing the directory in my code, but I can't find a way to access it locally.

I've seen the discussion about setting and environment variable "TMPDIR", but that seems not to work, either inline of using the `--env-vars env.json`

```
{
  "Parameters": {
        "TMPDIR": "/tmp"
  }
}
```

I'm running sam on Linux

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I am not sure how to access the /tmp file in AWS Lambda locally, so I'm trying to do this in the Docker container through a TMPDIR created on my local desktop -- that's not working either so far. I am trying to configure it in the template.yml file.